# Get master to do work in task farm

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have a small test code that acts as a task farm, with the master process sending tasks over to slaves.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to make the master take it's share of the work from the list of tasks. For example using a send and receive from the master to itself, but I'm not certain if this will complete cleanly.

The code is as follows:

```
###!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import sys
import os
import time




comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
#print(rank,size)


if rank == 0:
   tasks=([StopIteration] * (size-1))+[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
   status=MPI.Status()

   while tasks:
        comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status=status)
        data=tasks.pop()
        print("master sending data ",data," to rank", status.Get_source())
        comm.send(obj=data, dest=status.Get_source())
        print("master: done send. Data left: ",tasks)

else:
   print("slave", rank," entering loop")
   for task in iter(lambda: comm.sendrecv(dest=0), StopIteration):
       print("slave ", rank," recvd data", task)
       print("slave ", rank," going to sleep")
       time.sleep((task+0.5)*2*1.4)
```

Any bright suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: It will either require a separate thread in the master or a very complex logic that combines computation with non-blocking messaging. The simplest solution is to just start one more MPI process and instruct the MPI runtime to place that process on the same host as the master rank.

Answer (score 1):

Here are complete examples on how to code master-slave logic in mpi4py

https://github.com/luca-s/mpi-master-slave